# is there a way to store multiple type of objects in single cacheStore in apache ignite?

Tags: performance, caching, ignite, in-memory

I'm trying to do some in-memory calculations, I'm doing it by using Apache Ignite with CacheStore Implementations, where It insisting me to do cross cache joins, which are not working Efficiently.
so is there a way to do store multiple types of Objects in same cache store.

Comment: Do you want to use same CacheStore implementation for different caches?

Comment: yes..
the purpose is need to join caches (it should not be cross cache join but different types of objects) for ex.
Orders, Order Items

Comment: I dont think it will be possible with CacheStore. What are trying to achive? May be there is easier way?

Answer (score 1):

Ignite SQL performance does not depend on weather join is cross-cache or not. If you have performance issues, there should be another reason.

But in any case, you can store multiple data types in a single cache, there is no limitation. The way `CacheStore` is configured in this case depends of what implementation you use.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe I'm missing the point but can't you just have your things implement the same base class?

Comment: but need to typecast every time... after fetching.. however thats not going to solve, the keys may duplicate in that case.
ie. when Order, Order Item  have same IDs

Comment: You can create a helper class to get stuff out of the cache.  Each with a signature of the type you want.  So if you do `SomeTypeA a = helper.get('key')` you'll get the type without explicitly casting (the helper will cast) even though the keys are all of the same type .  If you really want to do this, I suggest you have non-overlapping keys between the objects.  You can do this easily by ids of different object types have different suffixes. So ids for Type A, B, C end in 001,002,003 respectively.